# 2010 : Get specific File from specific sub folder using CSOM C#

Tags: 2010, document-library, csom, caml, folder

I have a document library with following structure.

```
Document Library Name
|_FolderA
  |_SubFolderA
    |_FileName_A
|_FolderB
  |_SubFolderB
    |_FileName_A
```

Now I just want to update the field for `FileName_A` which is in `SubFolderB` in `FolderB`.

I am using following code:

```
List documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> " +
"<Query>" +
"<Where>" +
"<And>" +
"<Eq>" +
"<FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\" />" +
"<Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value>" +
"</Eq>" +
"<Eq>" +
"<FieldRef Name=\"LinkFilename\"/>" +
"<Value Type=\"Text\">" + FileName+ "</Value>" +
"</Eq>" +
"</And>" +
"</Where>" +
"</Query>" +
"</View>";
var inventionFolders = documentLibrary.GetItems(query);
clientContext.Load(documentLibrary);
clientContext.Load(documentLibrary.Fields);
clientContext.Load(inventionFolders, fs => fs.Include(fi => fi["Title"],
fi => fi["DisplayName"],
fi => fi["FileLeafRef"],
fi => fi[fieldName]
));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
if (inventionFolders.Count == 1)
{
// Do my stuff
}
```

This gives me the context of `FileName_A` which is in `SubFolderA` in `FolderA`.

Can anyone help in building CAML query for this requirement.

I tried with `ServerRelativeURL` and `Recursive` instead of `RecursiveAll`. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add below condition

```
<Eq>
        <FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" />
        <Value Type=\"Text\">/site/library/foldername</Value>
</Eq>
```

And use `RecursiveAll` to gets all files and all folders under the specified location.

Comment: I need to get the context particular file under sub folder

Comment: Then you should use clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl to retrieve the direct file context

Comment: I am using c# CSOM

Comment: Brother it's just a syntax.. If you can't figure out from this hint then how are you going to learn